# jquery slide down effect - without moving inner contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve a simple slide up/down effect similar to the 'more' link on www.bbc.co.uk

YOu can see that the inner contents do not move up and down, instead it is like a screen is being pulled over them.

Using jquery slideUp slideDown does not achieve this, instead the whole div is moved up and down so the text looks like it moves.

How can a similar effect be achieved using jquery?

Comment: that's not a problem of jquery, thats a problem of HTML layout and CSS styles

Comment: yes it will depend on how your layout is setup. Also what kind of styling you have. You could use a div that covers the area in question and that div is slid down to reveal what is underneath.

Comment: Did either of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your sliding div between the menu and the content:

```
<div id="menu">Menu example. Click <a href="#" onclick="$('#slide').slideDown();">here!</a></div>
<div id="slide">Whoa! sliding div<br>See how it moves the content down</div>
<div>Content here</div>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2hZme/1/

Answer (score 0):

`slideUp/slideDown` uses the top position when it animates, when you want to use the height. So I'd suggest to animate it manually:

```
// Initial variables
var panel = $('#panel');
var panelHeight = panel.height();

// Set the height to 0
panel.height('0px');

// Animate it to its initial size
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#panel').animate({'height' : panelHeight});
});
```

... and of course the CSS:

```
#panel {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px; /* or whatever */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fsQr/

Comment: Working on a fiddle... one sec